# Unknown column 'email' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, node.js, bcrypt

I am building a user registration and authentication system in nodejs. When I try to encrypt the password of the user and store it into my sql user database, it gives an error.

The implementation for registration controller is as follows:

```
var express=require("express");
var connection = require('./../config');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

module.exports.register=function(req,res){
    var today = new Date();
    var encryptedString = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 5);
    var user={
        "userid":req.body.userid,
        "password":encryptedString,
        "clientid":req.body.clientid,
        "email":req.body.email
    }
    connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?',user, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        res.json({
            status:false,
            message:'query error'
        })
      }else{
          res.json({
            status:true,
            data:results,
            message:'user registered sucessfully'
        })
      }
    });
}
```

The user table has the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `user`(
`userid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`clientid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`clientid`) REFERENCES `client`(`clientid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Without the password encryption, the user is stored successfully with the password being plaintext. Why does this issue occur upon encrypting the password?

Any help clarifying this would be appreciated.

This is the result for console.log(error):

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'email' in 'field list'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO user SET `userid` = '1', `password` = " +
    "'$2b$05$0D2eG3Jp.UhlYs.pbtYip.yMrCYkjhHiVZC3WwrtmKJG4pyRKZDae', " +
    "`clientid` = '1', `email` = 'abc@xyz.com'"
}
```

Comment: What is the length of the password field in table?

Comment: I have set it at 60

Comment: Check your password length after the hash. It might be a problem.

Comment: I took it up to 160 but it still gives the error. What can be the maximum length of a bcrypt hashing?

Comment: Please print or console your error. It will give you the reason for not storing information.

Comment: I'm a bit inexperienced with node, so could you advise how I should print it in the browser or on the command line?

Comment: if (error) { console.log(error) } } it will print error on command line.

Comment: I have edited the post with the error log

Comment: can you please use this static value `$2b$05$0D2eG3Jp.UhlYs.pbtYip.yMrCYkjhHiVZC3WwrtmKJG4pyRKZDae` to your password?

Comment: var user={
        "userid":req.body.userid,
        "password":'$2b$05$0D2eG3Jp.UhlYs.pbtYip.yMrCYkjhHiVZC3WwrtmKJG4pyRKZDae',
        "clientid":req.body.clientid,
        "email":req.body.email
    }

Comment: It was due to updating the table that my email column got deleted. The problem is solved now, no issue with the hashing it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unknown column 'email' in 'field list'

It is self explainatory. You have no email column in your table which confirms DDL you have provided.

```
`userid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`clientid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
```

no email

while you are sending it trough user

```
var user={
    "userid":req.body.userid,
    "password":encryptedString,
    "clientid":req.body.clientid,
    "email":req.body.email
}
```